# Image in <TD> not fitting the complete cell. (works fine in FF, but not in IE)

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am trying to add a background image for  element in the following way in css

### CSS

```css
.datebox {
    background-image: url("datebox.png");
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
```

### JSP

```
<td class="datebox" valign="top"> <Table>......</Table> </td>
```

When I view in FF, it displays fine. But in IE, the image is not filled completed in the cell.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot or even a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 2):

The cell won't automatically resize to the size of its background image. In order to make sure that the cell is the same size as the image, apply the image's dimensions to your `.datebox`, for example

```css
.datebox {
    width: 100px;
    height: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Background-size actually isn't supported in IE8 and less - See MSDN's IE [compatibility chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28VS.85%29.aspx#color)